# How to automate deployment of event hub and azure data explorer

Tags: azure-resource-manager, continuous-deployment, azure-eventhub, azure-data-explorer

I have my service hosted in two regions. In both the regions, I want separate event hubs and ADX cluster, database and 1 table.

In my use case the service will send the event datas to same region's event hub. From event hub, the events will be ingested in any of the 2 region's kusto cluster table based on the property of event data.

In more detail - Suppose there are 2 regions x and y. The request comes at service of region x with the property "homelocation=y". So the service will process the request and send the event data to x region's event hub with the property {Table:region-y-table"}. Now from this event hub, the data should be sent to region y's kusto table(region-y-table).
Similarly if any request comes at region y with property of "homelocation=x", that data should be sent to region x's kusto table(region-x-table).
Also the request coming to region x may contain the property "homelocation=x", in that case the data should be sent to region x's kusto table(region-x-table). Same for region y.
There will be many-to-many mapping between event hub and kusto tables. There will be 2x2 data connections in this scenario.

I have separate ADO release pipeline configured for deployment of service in both the regions.

My question is -

- How can I add the information of different region's kusto or event hub in another region's event hub and kusto ARM template?
- Since I will run the deployment one by one, so at the time of first event hub and kusto deployment there will be no other kusto and event hub present, how will I add the data connection in first region's kusto?
- If I introduce new region in future, how will old kusto be connected to new region's event hub using ARM template or script?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use a single ARM template deployment to deploy services to multiple regions. Each object in the ARM template has a location property, allowing for straightforward deployment across multiple regions within the same template

Having everything in a single ARM template offers the significant advantage of easily declaring dependencies between resources. This means you can clearly define the relationships and order of deployment for different resources, simplifying the management and coordination

If you wish to have many arm templates deploying each region separately
you can consider breaking it down into two templates. The first template would be responsible for creating the Kusto cluster, database, and event hub. The second template can then be used to create or update the data connection. This approach allows for a modular deployment strategy for each region.